# Are there any plans to make a sequel to the film Evolution (2001)

Tags: evolution

[Evolution](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0251075/) which I took as director Ivan Reitman's attempt to reboot the GhostBusters franchise. Was a good film (by my standards) and it's been more then ten years now since it's release. Is there any hope or speculation that a sequel will be made?

Comment: Call it ignorance, but how was it meant to be a way to reboot Ghostbusters?

Comment: Reboot was likely the wrong word, but Evolution was done in the same comedy style of GhostBusters. In an interview with Ivan he talks about how the three characters are similar to those in GhostBusters, and that the film is a modern take on that franchise.

Comment: Doubtful there would ever be a sequel to it as it performed so badly. However, there was a short-lived animated show on Fox Kids based on the film. Another Ghostbusters similarity?

Comment: @Nobby do you know the same of the cartoon? Was it obvious like "Evolution"?

Comment: I found it for you :) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alienators:_Evolution_Continues

Comment: thanks! Oh I remember watching it. It wasn't very good. lol

Comment: On the DVD commentary they reveal that this actually started as a serious sci-fi thriller, but when Reitman took over it became a comedy. And the _end villain_ wasn't a giant amoeba, but a highly evolved superbeing.

Comment: @nobby i'd put the animated show as an answer, because that seems to be the answer to me.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [a title's release date or rumors about a specific title or series](http://movies.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Considering *Evolution* was a pretty huge loss for Dreamworks ($40 million return against an $80 million budget (*not* including marketing)), it is unsurprising that a sequel was not green-lit.

That said, the filmmakers did indeed hope for it to be a new franchise in the same vein as *Ghostbusters* seeing as they produced a [short-lived animated show](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alienators%3a_Evolution_Continues) on Fox Kids based on the film.

Comment: The worldwide box office was [$98 million](http://boxofficemojo.com/movies/?id=evolution.htm). But even with _DVD sales_ and _TV rights_ they probably weren't able to at least break even.

Comment: Absolutely. Even back then, a film needed to double its budget to break even. Thanks for the B.O. Clarification.